# Capacitor Units For Power Factor Correction

Tags: voltage, capacitance

I have got the assignment to improve power factor of an industry. I have worked it out and found capacitance in K Vars and Micro Farads but need to know about the capacitor representation in volts?

Comment: The volt rating of the capacitor would be determined by the line voltage.

Answer (score -1):

You should get an ac capacitor rated for the mains voltage you are using.